# Unix search command

Tags: unix

I need Unix search command which is used to find a particular word in a line and that line should not contain particular word.

```
For eg,

Line 1: Java is my World.
Line 2: Java is OOPs language.
```

I need unix command which returns lines contains "Java" not "World" in that line.

```
Expected Output:

Java is OOPs language.
```

Thanks,
Srinivasan R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep:

```
cat <File> | grep 'Java' | grep -v 'World'
```

The -v option inverts selection (i.e. lines NOT containing pattern)

You could also do it with awk and give both conditions together:

```
cat <File> | awk '/Java/ && !/World/'
```

Comment: is it possible to use same search pattern for "more" command?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Could you try explaining that?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I would first filter, then pipe it to less|more. e.g.

`cat <File> | grep 'Java' | grep -v 'World' | more`

Answer (score 1):

First, list out all the files that have the word 'Java' in them and then inversely match 'World' i.e. select those lines which DO NOT have 'World' in them:

```
cat file | grep 'Java' | grep --invert-match 'World'
```

Answer (score 1):

Command for particular word

## grep -R dirname

## grep -R dirname > filename (to append output)

to find a particular word in a line and also search file name where that word is present.